# Why float number returns correct answer and not double?

Tags: java

I know that in Java, doubles use IEEE 754 floating point arithmetic (see this Wikipedia article), which is inherently inaccurate.

So the result of **2.00d - 1.10d** should be something like that:

```
0.8999999999999999
```

Ok, but what about float values?  Why the result of **2.00f - 1.10f** is

```
0.9
```

Comment: Short answer: coincidence, try this: `2.01f - 1.10f`

Comment: @grep You forgot to include the link to Wikipedia.

Comment: Long string of duplicates. This is the fourth layer.

Comment: Yeah seriously.. why do people link duplicates to other duplicates instead of the source?

Comment: Oh sorry, I did not know that it wad duplicate.

Comment: @BoDidely - Well in this case, this one is closer to the linked duplicate.  People are making a point ....